# Cohomology of $G_m$

Tags: galois-theory, homology-cohomology, etale-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Suppose $\overline{k}$ be an algebraic closure of a field $k$. Usually $G_k \colon= {\mathrm{Gal}}(\overline{k}/k)$ is endowed with the Krull topology. When considering Galois cohomology $H^1({\mathrm{Gal}}(\overline{k}/k), {\overline{k}}^{\times})$, the continuous cochains are taken into account.

**Q.** Suppose we consider merely a cochain $\rho$ which satisfies $\rho(\sigma \circ \tau) = \rho(\tau)^{\sigma} \rho(\sigma) \in {\overline{k}}^{\times}$ for all $\sigma, \tau \in {\mathrm{Gal}}(\overline{k}/k)$ and is *not* supposed to be continuous.
Then, is it true that we have still $H^1({\mathrm{Gal}}(\overline{k}/k), {\overline{k}}^{\times}) = 0$?

Comment: Nice question. I don't know, but I think it is likely to be false (for appropriate choice of $k$): since the action of $\text{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$ on $\overline{k}^\times$ is continuous, any coboundary is continuous, so as long as a discontinuous cochain exists at all it gives rise to a non-zero class in cohomology.

Comment: I also don't know the answer, but again I suspect this is false. I'd suspect you can find a counterexample with $Gal(\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p/\mathbb{F}_p) \cong \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ since as an abstract group $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is pretty scary, so heuristically I'd expect it to have pretty scary cohomology.